# Remove special characters (in list) in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of special characters which are in a list like:

```
special=[r'''\\''', r'''+''', r'''-''', r'''&''', r'''|''', r'''!''', r'''(''', r''')''', r'''{''', r'''}''',\
     r'''[''', r''']''', r'''^''', r'''~''', r'''*''', r'''?''', r''':''', r'''"''', r''';''', r''' ''']
```

And I have a string:

```
stringer="Müller my [ string ! is cool^&"
```

How do I make this replacement? I am expecting:

```
stringer = "Müller my string is cool"
```

Also, is there some builtin to replace these ‘special’ chars in Python?

Comment: You have blank space as a special character, so I would expect all blank spaces to be replaced, but they are not. Why?

Comment: Also, by "replace" you mean "remove" right?

Comment: @NPE: yes, I am sorry I was not clear earlier - edited this now. Thanks a tonne for point this out.

Comment: @AJW Why are *some* spaces removed and others not?

Comment: Is there some reason why the characters are in a list, rather than a string, eg: `r'\\+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:"; '` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring: if it is a string, does it make like easier?

Comment: Well, it makes the code easier to read, which is always a bonus.  I'm pretty sure that if you use a string instead of a list the character testing speed would be significantly faster, but using a set would be even faster still. Of course, you can easily "convert" a list or string into a set with `special = set(special)`.

Comment: BTW, in your `special` list there's no need for all those triple-quotes: they're used when you have multi-line strings. Also, if the first element of `special` is supposed to be a single backslash, then it should be `'\\'`. As you may have noticed, raw strings that end with a single backslash don't work very well. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a simple generator expression:

```
>>> ''.join(ch for ch in stringer if ch not in special)
'M\xc3\xbcllermystringiscool'
```

**Note that this also removes the spaces**, since they're in your `special` list (the last element). If you don't want them removed, either don't include the space in `special` or do modify the `if` check accordingly.

Comment: Straight solution. You can make it better by using a list comprehension instead of generator expression within `join`.

Comment: What Kasra said. Also, it'd be a little more efficient if `special` were a set.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the space from your specials you can do it using `re.sub()` but note that first you need to escape the special regex characters.

```
In [58]: special=[r'''\\''', r'''+''', r'''-''', r'''&''', r'''|''', r'''!''', r'''(''', r''')''', r'''{''', r'''}''',\
     r'''[''', r''']''', r'''^''', r'''~''', r'''*''', r'''?''', r''':''', r'''"''', r''';''']

In [59]: print re.sub(r"[{}]".format(re.escape(''.join(special))), '', stringer, re.U)
Müller my  string  is cool
```